# Technicality: Post greyed out?

Tags: support

What does it mean when the text of an answer is greyed out? Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545959/how-can-i-show-that-this-operator-is-bounded-on-l2/2546117?noredirect=1#2545959) for example: Guy FSone's answer appears as grey text on a white background; it becomes black text as usual when I hover the mouse over it. It's not marked closed or deleted or on hold or anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it has a score of -3 or less.

Comment: Ah - that would explain why I hadn't seen this before: Typically the poster gets the hint and deletes it by that point.